# UINavigationController loses swipe back function when top bar is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem in that in swift when i set the UINavigationController to hidden using

```
        navController.navigationBarHidden = true
```

it also stops the swipe back ability on any viewcontrollers that are pushed onto the stack. there doesn't seem to be any accepted fix, and i've tried setting the interactivePopGestureRecogniser as suggested by others, but this doesn't work any more either (i think that may have worked in swift 1?)

pls halp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own interactive gesture and animation (called an *interactive custom transition animation*). It can be just like the default swipe gesture, or you can use use a different gesture and a different animation.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way of having the default gesture while the bar is hidden? I know in Obj-C you could do it, so figured it would be there somewhere in swift.